# Could not load file or assembly MSCaptcha WFFM in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore8

I am getting this error when I am using Captcha field type.

> Could not load file or assembly 'MSCaptcha, Version=4.0.4250.31585, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b9ff12f28cdcf412' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

Answer (score 1):

**MSCaptcha.dll** is a part of Web Forms for Marketers. Make sure you have got that installed with your solutions. Version 4.0.4250.31585 is the one that ships with WFFM 8.0 (but may also ship with few previous versions)

It is referenced from **Sitecore.Forms.Core.dll** and has its own config:

```
\Include\Captcha.config
```

The least you can do is just place missing DLL manually, however it may end up with the some other DLLs missing.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that MSCaptcha is really ancient and support for it has stopped a long time ago.  The biggest drawback is that this is not supported in a web farm environment.  Submitting a form could bounce the user to another server in a load-balanced environment and the other server has no clue what the captcha text was from the previous server and fail everytime this happens.  I strongly suggest choosing another standalone Captcha assembly if you operate in a distributed environment.